# "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" while using make in Mac M1

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, operating-system, clang++

Alright, so I want to build a cross compiler on my system. I was setting up the environment to work on OSdev. While building the GCC-Cross compiler I am facing an error as:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [full-stamp] Error 1
make: *** [all-build-fixincludes] Error
```

I have downloaded the GCC files and set up the configuration to build. I am getting this error on using command

```
sudo make all-gcc
```

Here's the makefile: https://pastebin.com/cbBqwPBn

Thanks a lot in advance. I've been stuck into this for the past couple of days.

It's a MacBook Air M1 64 bit. I am following [this one](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) for reference.